# Paypal Transaction ID

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, paypal

I am using PayPal for payments in my Ionic application.
I'm getting a transaction code like: PAY-0US81985GW1191216KOY7OXA,
But in the transaction history on the PayPal website, the transaction code looks like: 3CC23774TG6379823.
With some research, I found this link as a solution: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_get
But I have no idea how to use this in my Ionic project.

Has anyone ever experienced this? Do you know how to help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The PAY-xxx ID is like a token that gets used during the API call procedure to process the payment.  The other one is the actual transaction ID associated with the transaction itself.

Comment: And you can tell me what I can do to sync these IDs? What I want is to end a payment, I'm generating a QRCode and I'd like the ID of the transaction to be included in it, but I can not do that.